# Getting Devise 1.3.4 to send emails with Gmail in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer

I'm trying to setup devise 1.3.4 to send emails via gmail while in development mode. I should mention that I'm using Rails 3.0.4 and Ruby 1.9.2p136.

I've tried the following in config/environments/development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'mydomain.com' }

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "mydomain.com",  
  :user_name            => "info",  
  :password             => "secret",  
  :authentication       => "plain",  
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  
}
```

And in config/initializers/devise.rb I changed

```
 config.mailer_sender = "please-change-me-at-config-initializers-devise@example.com"
```

To

```
 config.mailer_sender = "info@mydomain.com"
```

Then I tried

http://yekmer.posterous.com/devise-gmail-smtp-configuration

It's still not working.

Is there a wiki page on how to get the mailer working? I see the email in my log and it looks great! The links work, etc ... I just want to see them in my email account.

---

Edit

I found the answer -
I used http://yekmer.posterous.com/devise-gmail-smtp-configuration - I had been putting that code in config/intializers/devise.rb when I should have been putting it in config/environments/development.rb.

Comment: The link which identifies how you solved this is no longer valid.  Could you add more detail to your post?

Comment: Here is a complete Rails project that I've open sourced that has mail with gmail and devise setup. https://github.com/cyrusstoller/RevTilt let me know if you need help setting the environment variables used in config/initializers/setup_mail.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {  
  :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",  
  :port                 => 587,  
  :domain               => "gmail.com",  
  :user_name            => "myinfo@gmail.com",  
  :password             => "secret",  
  :authentication       => "plain"
  # :enable_starttls_auto => true # I don't have this, but it should work anyway 
}
```

--------- **EDIT**

it it's sent maybe you don't receive it because of the spam filter, first thing to check:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default :from => "myinfo@gmail.com"
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Tried that with a gmail account I have. it still says that the email has been sent, but then I never receive it. I put that code in the block for ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings.

Comment: try then going to that account and check it the mail has been sent

Comment: I'm using google apps. I just logged in to see if it had sent any emails ... looks like it hasn't.

Comment: I want to make the Devise mailer work, but if it doesn't I guess I could write my own a la http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/ca8d3cc8d4012a4b

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out - I put my solution above.

Answer (score 2):

you should put that in devise initializer :

```
# Configure the class responsible to send e-mails.
  config.mailer = "YourAppDeviseMailer"
```

Then create a class that extends Devise::Mailer :

```
class YourAppDeviseMailer < Devise::Mailer
  default :from => 'your_email'

  def self.mailer_name
    "devise/mailer"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can change it inside config/initializers/devise.rb. No need for a new class I think?

```
#config/initializers/devise.rb
config.mailer_sender = 'youremail@gmail.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value of ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method is :smtp