# I can't reindex with Sunspot anymore because of tlsmail gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot

Ever since I installed the `tlsmail` gem and [setup my Google Apps account to take in email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933969/getting-devise-1-3-4-to-send-emails-with-gmail-in-development) I can't [reindex with Sunspot](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot). Before this it was working. Now when I run `rake sunspot:reindex` I get:

```
rake sunspot:reindex --trace
(in C:/apper)
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806: warning: already initialized constant SMTPSession
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687: warning: already initialized constant POP
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688: warning: already initialized constant POPSession
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689: warning: already initialized constant POP3Session
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702: warning: already initialized constant APOPSession
** Invoke sunspot:reindex (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:reindex
rake aborted!
Solr Response: Severe_errors_in_solr_configuration___Check_your_log_files_for_more_detailed_information_on_what_may_be_wrong___If_you_want_solr_to_continue_after_configuration_erro
rs_change_____abortOnConfigurationErrorfalseabortOnConfigurationError___in_null_____javalangRuntimeException_Cant_find_resource_solrconfigxml_in_classpath_or_Cappersolrconf_cwdcR
uby192librubygems191gemssunspot121solr___at_orgapachesolrcoreSolrResourceLoaderopenResourceSolrResourceLoaderjava260___at_orgapachesolrcoreSolrResourceLoaderopenConfigSolrResourceL
oaderjava228___at_orgapachesolrcoreConfiginitConfigjava101___at_orgapachesolrcoreSolrConfiginitSolrConfigjava130___at_orgapachesolrcoreCoreContainer$Initia...........................
```

You can see the full trace here: https://gist.github.com/1580444

I have no clue what's going on. Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a Solr configuration error (e.g. **Severe_errors_in_solr_configuration**).  Check the log in the Solr directory, perhaps your schema.xml is incorrect?

Comment: Thank you, yeah I had to do re-run and get a fresh new schema.