# warning: already initialized constant after installing tlsmail gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

After I installed the `tlsmail` [gem for email delivery to my gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933969/getting-devise-1-3-4-to-send-emails-with-gmail-in-development) account, these erros keep coming up every time I run a rake command:

```
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/smtp.rb:806: warning: already initialized constant SMTPSession
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:687: warning: already initialized constant POP
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:688: warning: already initialized constant POPSession
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:689: warning: already initialized constant POP3Session
c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/tlsmail-0.0.1/lib/net/pop.rb:702: warning: already initialized constant APOPSession
```

How can I get rid of these warnings?

---

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.10'
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem "pg", "0.12.0"
gem "cancan", "1.6.7"
gem "geocoder", "1.0.5"
gem "will_paginate", "3.0.2"
gem "rails3-jquery-autocomplete"
gem "jquery-rails", "1.0.19"
gem "dynamic_form", "1.1.4"
gem "devise", "1.5.3"
gem "thin", "1.3.1"
gem 'sunspot_rails', '1.2.1'
gem "tlsmail"
```

Comment: Do you have another gem installed related to email that might be declaring similarly named constants?

Comment: @normalocity I don't think so? I posted my gem file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least, it seems, that you're not alone. I'm not terribly familiar with that gem, but it looks like this might be a fix for you: http://blog.snootymonkey.com/post/892799550/already-initialized-constant-warnings

It's possible that ActionMailer (or some other mailer code/plugin) is included by default as part of Rails 3. Don't quote me on that, but that's my unsubstantiated hunch as far as where the conflicting names might be coming from.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to modify the gem, try this:

```
require 'net/smtp'
Net.instance_eval {remove_const :SMTPSession} if defined?(Net::SMTPSession)

require 'net/pop'
Net::POP.instance_eval {remove_const :Revision} if defined?(Net::POP::Revision)
Net.instance_eval {remove_const :POP} if defined?(Net::POP)
Net.instance_eval {remove_const :POPSession} if defined?(Net::POPSession)
Net.instance_eval {remove_const :POP3Session} if defined?(Net::POP3Session)
Net.instance_eval {remove_const :APOPSession} if defined?(Net::APOPSession)

require 'tlsmail'
```

Preloading the `net/smtp` and `net/pop` gems and killing the constants prevents `tlsmail` from trying to load and write over the constants. It's a filthy, filthy hack ... but it works!

(Ruby 1.9.2, tlsmail 0.0.1)

Comment: @jackocnr Be sure to modify your Gemfile like this: `gem 'tlsmail', require: false` and place the above in `config/initializers/tlsmail.rb`, for example

Comment: require: false was what I was missing. Thanks @aceofspades

Answer (score 0):

tlsmail was a backport of ruby 1.9 mail to 1.8. So you don't need tlsmail in ruby 1.9 or later.

> This library dynamically replace net/smtp and net/pop with these in ruby 1.9 and
>   enables pop or smtp via SSL/TLS.

http://rubydoc.info/gems/tlsmail/0.0.1/frames