# Setting up a gmail with devise confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, gmail

I want to setup a gmail account to send out the confirmation emails and reset emails for when signing up on my Ruby on Rails site. I just want to use a gmail account for now, and switch to a proper like noreply@mydomain.com later.

I've gotten so it doesn't get any errors when it runs. I can create an account, it generates the correct views and everything, and Mailcatcher says it sends the email. It doesn't however say the email was sent on the gmail account nor do I see the email in my inbox or spam folder.

I tried following numerous guides and stackoverflow questions, but I can't seem to figure it out. Such as [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933969/getting-devise-1-3-4-to-send-emails-with-gmail-in-development), and others but no luck. Any help?

I setup /initializers/devise.rb file with...

```
config.mailer_sender = 'shiplistconfrimation@gmail.com'
...
config.reconfirmable = false
```

Then my development.rb file like so...

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :domain               => "gmail.com",
    :user_name            => "shiplistconfrimation@gmail.com",
    :password             => "<PASSWORD>",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :ssl                  => true,
    :tsl                  => true
    # :enable_starttls_auto => true # I don't have this, but it should work anyway
  }
```

With being my password removed from this question.

Comment: can you removed ssl and tsl and put `enable_starttls_auto: true`

Comment: Remove `config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}`

Comment: it works for me checkout this `https://launchschool.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails`

Comment: Adding enable_starttls_auto: true and removing that smtp_settings line worked thank you! Is this just because like different versions of rails this has all changed?

Comment: No that was not the cause it is because of wrong configration I think so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do following things

ADD in ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings

`enable_starttls_auto: true`

REMOVE

`config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:address => "localhost", :port => 1025}`

This will solve your issue